# Set constraint for the last row of Tableview

Tags: uitableview, constraints

I am using a static table in `UITableViewController`, I want the height of the last row of the table is bigger than others and the bottom of it has a zero constraint to `safeArea.buttom` .
First I added the last row of table view as an outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var lastRowOfCell: UITableViewCell!
```

Then I added these line to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` 
but none of them  works:

```
lastRowOfCell.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
lastRowOfCell.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method 
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == ('lastRow') {
            return heightNeeded
        }
    }`

And replace 'last row' with the row you need
and heightNeeded with the pixels or height constraints required